# Excel VBA: parsing JSON

Tags: json, excel, vba, parsing

Hope somebody might able to help me.
I am a real rookie in this field, had a friend of mine write up the following code some time ago.
I have VB in Excel that gets data from a yahoo API, URL: "https://query2.finance.yahoo.com/v8/finance/chart/" & ticker & "?interval=1m&range=1d"

The data gets inserted in excel and is auto-refreshed every minute.
Everything works smoothly with no issues.
Now to the challange, since the data gets auto purged after a day in the excel, I would need to extend the amount of data (rows) from the current 1 day to 7 days.
So I tried simply to change the URL from the above mentioned to the following:
"https://query2.finance.yahoo.com/v8/finance/chart/" & ticker & "?interval=1m&range=7d"

However the parsing in the code gives me errors which I am to bad at solving..
First warning comes in the code:
"Case Else: If token(p + 1) <> ":" Then dic.Add key, token(p)"

And the whole code is as below (feel free to try it in excel if you would like), thanks in advance.

```
Option Explicit
Private p&, token, dic

Function ParseJSON(json$, Optional key$ = "obj") As Object
p = 1
token = Tokenize(json)
Set dic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
If token(p) = "{" Then ParseObj key Else ParseArr key
Set ParseJSON = dic
End Function

Function ParseObj(key$)
Do: p = p + 1
    Select Case token(p)
        Case "]"
        Case "[":  ParseArr key
        Case "{":  ParseObj key
        Case "{"
                   If token(p + 1) = "}" Then
                       p = p + 1
                       dic.Add key, "null"
                   Else
                       ParseObj key
                   End If
            
        Case "}":  key = ReducePath(key): Exit Do
        Case ":":  key = key & "." & token(p - 1)
        Case ",":  key = ReducePath(key)
        Case Else: If token(p + 1) <> ":" Then dic.Add key, token(p)
    End Select
Loop
End Function

Function ParseArr(key$)
Dim e&
Do: p = p + 1
    Select Case token(p)
        Case "}"
        Case "{":  ParseObj key & ArrayID(e)
        Case "[":  ParseArr key
        Case "]":  Exit Do
        Case ":":  key = key & ArrayID(e)
        Case ",":  e = e + 1
        Case Else: dic.Add key & ArrayID(e), token(p)
    End Select
Loop
End Function

Function Tokenize(s$)
Const Pattern = """(([^""\\]|\\.)*)""|[+\-]?(?:0|[1-9]\d*)(?:\.\d*)?(?:[eE][+\-]?\d+)?|\w+| 
[^\s""']+?"
Tokenize = RExtract(s, Pattern, True)
End Function

Function RExtract(s$, Pattern, Optional bGroup1Bias As Boolean, Optional bGlobal As Boolean = True)
Dim c&, m, n, v
With CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
.Global = bGlobal
.MultiLine = False
.IgnoreCase = True
.Pattern = Pattern
If .TEST(s) Then
  Set m = .Execute(s)
  ReDim v(1 To m.Count)
  For Each n In m
    c = c + 1
    v(c) = n.Value
    If bGroup1Bias Then If Len(n.submatches(0)) Or n.Value = """""" Then v(c) = n.submatches(0)
  Next
End If
End With
RExtract = v
End Function

Function ArrayID$(e)
ArrayID = "(" & e & ")"
End Function

Function ReducePath$(key$)
If InStr(key, ".") Then ReducePath = Left(key, InStrRev(key, ".") - 1) Else ReducePath = key
End Function

Function ListPaths(dic)
Dim s$, v
For Each v In dic
    s = s & v & " --> " & dic(v) & vbLf
Next
Debug.Print s
End Function

Function GetFilteredValues(dic, match)
Dim c&, i&, v, w
v = dic.keys
ReDim w(1 To dic.Count)
For i = 0 To UBound(v)
    If v(i) Like match Then
        c = c + 1
        w(c) = dic(v(i))
    End If
Next
ReDim Preserve w(1 To c)
GetFilteredValues = w
End Function

Function GetFilteredTable(dic, cols)
Dim c&, i&, j&, v, w, z
v = dic.keys
z = GetFilteredValues(dic, cols(0))
ReDim w(1 To UBound(z), 1 To UBound(cols) + 1)
For j = 1 To UBound(cols) + 1
     z = GetFilteredValues(dic, cols(j - 1))
     For i = 1 To UBound(z)
        w(i, j) = z(i)
     Next
Next
GetFilteredTable = w
End Function

Function OpenTextFile$(f)
With CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
    .Charset = "utf-8"
    .Open
    .LoadFromFile f
    OpenTextFile = .ReadText
End With
End Function

Function toUnix(dt) As Long
toUnix = DateDiff("s", "1/1/1970 00:00:00", dt)
End Function

Function fromUnix(ts) As Date
fromUnix = DateAdd("s", ts, "1/1/1970 00:00:00")
End Function

Private Sub GetData()

' Queue next invocation
Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:01:00"), "GetData"

Dim DataSheet As Worksheet
Set DataSheet = Sheets("Data")

Dim ParameterSheet As Worksheet
Set ParameterSheet = Sheets("Parameters")


Dim scrape As String
scrape = ParameterSheet.Range("B2").Value

If scrape <> "TRUE" Then
    Exit Sub
End If

Dim ticker As String
ticker = ParameterSheet.Range("A2").Value

Dim url As String
url = "https://query2.finance.yahoo.com/v8/finance/chart/" & ticker & "?interval=1m&range=1d"

Dim hReq As Object
Set hReq = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    With hReq
        .Open "GET", url, False
        .Send
    End With

Dim json As Object
Set json = ParseJSON(hReq.ResponseText)

Dim closes As Variant
closes = GetFilteredValues(json, "*.close*")

Dim opens As Variant
opens = GetFilteredValues(json, "*.open*")

Dim volumes As Variant
volumes = GetFilteredValues(json, "*.volume*")

Dim highs As Variant
highs = GetFilteredValues(json, "*.high*")

Dim lows As Variant
lows = GetFilteredValues(json, "*.low*")

Dim timestamps As Variant
timestamps = GetFilteredValues(json, "*.timestamp*")

Dim i As Integer
i = UBound(timestamps) + 1

Dim row As Integer
row = 2

' Load new data in
Dim timestamp As Variant
For Each timestamp In timestamps
    i = i - 1
    timestamp = Int(timestamps(i) / 60) * 60

    If "null" = closes(i) Then
        GoTo Continue
    End If
    
    If DataSheet.Range("H" & row).Value = "" Then
    ' Empty dataset
    ElseIf toUnix(DataSheet.Range("H" & row).Value) < timestamp Then
    ' There is new data, prepend
        DataSheet.Rows(row).Insert
    ElseIf toUnix(DataSheet.Range("H" & row).Value) = timestamp Then
    ' Replace old data,
    Else: GoTo Continue
    End If

    DataSheet.Range("B" & row).Value = ticker
    DataSheet.Range("C" & row).Value = opens(i)
    DataSheet.Range("D" & row).Value = highs(i)
    DataSheet.Range("E" & row).Value = lows(i)
    DataSheet.Range("F" & row).Value = closes(i)
    DataSheet.Range("G" & row).Value = volumes(i)
    DataSheet.Range("H" & row).Value = fromUnix(timestamp)
    row = row + 1
Continue:
Next timestamp

' Remove data that is more then 10 days old
row = 1
Do While True
    row = row + 1
    Dim datee As Variant
    datee = DataSheet.Range("H" & row).Value

    If datee = "" Then
        Exit Do
    End If

    If toUnix(datee) + 864000 < toUnix(Now()) Then
        DataSheet.Rows(row).EntireRow.Delete
        row = row - 1 ' This prevents skipping the next line
    End If
Loop

End Sub

Private Sub Auto_Open()
GetData
End Sub
```

Comment: Yikes - there are good JSON parsers available for VBA, such as https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON

Comment: seeing code posted containing `Auto_Open` method that calls another method with `Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:01:00"), "CallMySelf"` with 1-rep OP saying "...feel free to try it in excel..." gives me the heebie jeebies. Code looks non-threatening on inspection, but just had to say it.

Comment: try using ?interval=1d&range=7d

Comment: Thanks for trying to help.
Was only referring to the "try in excel" if you could  reproduce the error, after changing it to 7d (in the url).
I am not good enough to recode this, so I basically were hoping if somebody with good skills would be able to assist me with this :).

CDP1802 - Does not work, if I change the URL to 7d, it will throw an error on:
"Case Else: If token(p + 1) <> ":" Then dic.Add key, token(p)"

Comment: If someone has suggestions how and what to rewrite in order to make the 7d work, I'd be more than happy try out that code, since I really want this to work with the 7d

Comment: It's the interval you need to change to 1d assuming you want daily figures. I have tried your code and it worked for me. the json came back with `"dataGranularity":"1d","range":"7d"`

Comment: Hi CDP1802.
Where should I change it from 1 day to 7 days?
I have tried changing it from:
"https://query2.finance.yahoo.com/v8/finance/chart/" & ticker & "?interval=1m&range=1d"

to

"https://query2.finance.yahoo.com/v8/finance/chart/" & ticker & "?interval=1m&range=7d"

But it simply throws me an error on:
"Case Else: If token(p + 1) <> ":" Then dic.Add key, token(p)"


The whole code works if its run with 1d, but not with 7d, unfortunately..

Comment: The interval=1m is wrong it should be `interval=1mo` for each month or `interval=1d` for each day. To get 7 days the `range=7d`.So correct parameter is `?interval=1d&range=7d`. You can see using browser in the response '"validRanges":["1d","5d","1mo","3mo","6mo","1y","2y","5y","10y","ytd","max"]},' 7d seems to work though.

Comment: Hi,
I see your point, but the interval needs to stay for 1m, since the data need to be in 1 minute intervals and not 1 days intervals.
So if I would run the following in the browser, it lists everything fine:
https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v8/finance/chart/AAPL?interval=1m&range=7d

Comment: Hi, I have identified the problem. The parser cannot deal with multiple trading periods which are arrays within an array `[[{}],[{}],[{}]]`. I'm working on a fix but it might be easier just to use the parser Tim suggested which I have proved works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is the parsing code cannot deal with the multiple trading periods which in the JSON are arrays within arrays `[[{}],[{}],[{}]]` when the range is greater than 1 day. The array index counter e is reset at each opening bracket so you get identical keys for each trading period. Dictionary keys must be unique hence the error. The best solution would be to rewrite using a modern parser but as a quick-fix hack the ParseArr function as follows ;

```vb
Function ParseArr(key$)

    'Dim e& move to top of script
    ' add this line
    If InStr(1, key, "tradingPeriods") = 0 Then e = 0

    Do: p = p + 1
       ' no change to this code
    Loop

End Function
```

Comment: Hi CDP1802,

Thanks for all the valuable input, appreciate it. Think I understand your explanation of the problem, gonna try and see if someone might be able to rewrite according to your suggestion =).
For the quickfix, should something be removed from the code or just add the function at the bottom / top ?

Comment: @philomel the function ParseArr is existing in your code just move the dim e outside the function to the top after the Private line,  and add the line I showed. I have rewritten your code using better parser but still testing it, should have it done by tomorrow.

Comment: Thank you so much @CDP1802 !
Works like a charm, really appreciate the help, just tried it and everything ran smoothly, thanks a million :) !